# Can't Load asset as XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xna, monogame

I have done my project with XNA and I'm currently trying to convert it while using Monogame.

My problem is that i can't load my XML file.

the error: `Could not load Level asset as a non-content file!`

My code:  `file = Content.Load<XmlData[]>(path);`

Path = xml name file without extension. (i tried both).

class XMLData :

```
public class XmlData
{
    public int id;
    public int posx;
    public int posy;
    public int rot;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
}
```

and some of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Asset Type="MyDataTypes.XmlData[]">
    <Item>
      <id>17</id>
      <posx>54</posx>
      <posy>30</posy>
      <rot>90</rot>
      <Width>184</Width>
      <Height>5</Height>
    </Item>
```

I had a problem like this with XNA, I had to add the following line to my XML file `<XnaContent> </XnaContent>`
and I also had to add XML data as a library (even if it was only one class).

So what's the difference with Monogame? Why I can't load this XML file? In propriety, my xml file is a content.

Thanks for any help, I'll be grateful.

Edit: I thought I had found my problem here --> `<Asset Type="MyDataTypes.XmlData[]">`
I tried `<Asset Type="XmlData[]">` cause i don't have MyDataTypes library anymore. I also tried with Content directory and asset directory. Nothing worked yet. I keep this post update.

Comment: I'll assume it's a typo on the question and not your code, but don't you need to close the Asset tag?

Comment: Sure i know XML, the Asset tag is close.

Comment: Have you added the Content directly to your MonoGame project? Are you able to load other files?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the property file as `Copy if newer`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you cannot do that in monogame, as it does not have a content pipeline to convert the xml to xnb files, so, unless I'm mistaken, your better off to build the files in xna and just copy the xnb files in to your monogame project and set them to "Content" and "Copy if newer"