# Error in XML document

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

i'm trying to Deserialize an Xml document to an array of object. I did it with Xna but for monogame i have to change my method.

this is how i deserialize :

```
public static XmlData[] DeserializeFromXml<XmlData>(string inputFile)

    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlData));
        XmlData[] deserializedObject = default(XmlData[]);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputFile);
        //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contents);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            deserializedObject = (XmlData[])s.Deserialize(textReader);
        }

        return deserializedObject;
    }
```

my class XmlData :

```
public class XmlData
{
    public int id;
    public int posx;
    public int posy;
    public int rot;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
}
```

my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Asset Type="XmlData[]">
    <Item>
      <id>17</id>
      <posx>54</posx>
      <posy>30</posy>
      <rot>90</rot>
      <Width>184</Width>
      <Height>5</Height>
    </Item>
  <Item>
      <id>1</id>
      <posx>200</posx>
      <posy>120</posy>
      <rot>0</rot>
      <Width>100</Width>
      <Height>90</Height>
    </Item>
</Asset>
```

And i have the following error :

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 1). (i'm using monogame)
```

Comment: Your root's closing tag has a first letter down-case.

Comment: Is the fact that the opening tag is `Asset` (with an uppercase A) and the closing tag `asset` a typo in the question, or is your XML content like that?

Comment: Nop missclick, both are uppercase

Comment: try returning List<XmlData> and this XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<XmlData>));

Comment: @Gabson: Seems you asked the same question before [Can't Load asset as XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548783/cant-load-asset-as-xml-file) ??

Comment: Yes i finally tried several options, this one seems the best, but i neelp to fix it. I ll try this @terrybozzio Same error message, maybe my Xml file is not well formated, but i don't see where.

Comment: please check out my answer it will most certainly do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @terrybozzio i finally find a way to read my xml file, before i had to convert it to a stream. But With **Monogame Framework** not alll methods are implemented.

Way to do it :

```
  public static List<XmlData> DeserializeFromXml(string inputFile)
    {
        List<XmlData> mydata = new List<XmlData>();
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<XmlData>), new XmlRootAttribute("Asset"));
        //XmlData[] deserializedObject = default(XmlData[]);
       // byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputFile);
     //   byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputfile);
       // MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        Stream test = TitleContainer.OpenStream("pets.xml");
        using (TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(test))
        {
            mydata = (List<XmlData>)s.Deserialize(txtReader);
        }

        return mydata;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputFile);
```

You are trying to decode the filename here not the filecontent.

Try something like

```
using (StreamReader reader = StreamReader(inputFile,Encoding.UTF8,true)) 
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlData));
    return (XmlData[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: I could not send the filename to StreamReader(); so how to fix that ?

Comment: First argument is a stream and not a string. Thats why i used MemoryStream

Comment: Yes? Thats one of the multiple Constructor Overloads of StreamReader you can choose from. I took a more fitting one. Is there a question behind your comment?

Answer (score 1):

Ok This will work on your xml file:

```
public static List<XmlData> DeserializeFromXml(string inputFile)
{
     List<XmlData> mydata = new List<XmlData>();
     XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<XmlData>),new XmlRootAttribute("Asset"));
     //XmlData[] deserializedObject = default(XmlData[]);
     //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputFile);
     //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contents);
     //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
     using (TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(inputFile))
     {
        mydata = (List<XmlData>)s.Deserialize(txtReader);
     }

     return mydata;
}
```

Change `<Item>` to `<XmlData>` and you are well, or, place this in your XmlData class declaration:

```
[XmlType("Item")]
public class XmlData
```

Comment: I have the following message : "Impossible to convert string in stream" at line `new streamreader(inputFile)`

Comment: I had to uncomment line `Memorystream = new streamreader();` but i think i try to deserialize hte string. I think the constructor streamReader(string) is not handled by my framework. If you could help me to resolve that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code !!

```
       using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(yourfile))
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
            var programs= from programItem in xdoc.Root.Elements()
                          select new xmldata {
                Id  = Convert.ToInt32( programItem.Attribute("Id").Value),
                posx  = Convert.ToInt32(   programItem.Attribute("posx").Value),
                poxy = Convert.ToInt32( programItem.Attribute("poxy").Value),
            };

            result = programs.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Don't find XmlTextReader, maybe cuase i'm using Monogame but never saw that before.

Comment: only need to add the library   System.Xml.XmlReader or
    System.Xml.XmlTextReader